# i have multiple txt files in 1 folder and I need to insert the txt data into MySql table using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have Multiple txt file in a folder. I need to insert the data from the txt file into mySql table
I also need to sort the files by modified date before inserting the data into the sql table named TAR.

below is the file inside one of the txt file. I also need to remove the first character in every line

```
SSerial1234
CCustomer
IDivision
Nat22
nAembly
rA0
PFVT
fchassis1-card-linec
RUnk
TP
Oeka
[06/22/2020 10:11:50
]06/22/2020 10:27:22
```

My code only reads all the files in the folder and prints the contents of the file. im not sure how to sort the files before reading the files 1 by 1.

Is there also a way to read only a specific file (JPE*.log)

```
import os

for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\TAR\TARS_Source/"):
    for f in files:
        fileName = os.path.join(path, f)
        with open(fileName, "r") as myFile:
            print(myFile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use glob.glob method to get all files using a regex like following...

```
import glob 
files=glob.glob('./JPE*.log')
```

And you can use following to sort files

```
sorted_files=sorted(files)
```